# Replacement rule from list to powers

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I would like to write a replacement rule that gives all the possible products of traces for a given length. For example, all the possible partitions of length `3` can be obtained as follows:

```
IntegerPartitions[3]
(*{{3}, {2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}*)
```

Each sublist gives the power in the trace, i.e. each sublist carries the following meaning:

$$\lbrace k_1,k_2,\ldots , k_n \rbrace \to \text{tr}\ a^{k_1}\ \text{tr}\ a^{k_2} \ldots \text{tr}\ a^{k_n}\,. \tag{1}$$

Hence the output of the seeked replacement rule should be (here for length `3`):

```
IntegerPartitions[3]/.rule
(*{tr[a^3],tr[a^2]tr[a],tr[a]^3}*)
```

I hope it is clear enough! How can this be achieved?

Comment: `rule = p_?VectorQ :> Times @@ (tr /@ (a^p)); IntegerPartitions[3] /. rule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ip = IntegerPartitions[3]

Times @@@ Map[tr, a^ip, {2}]
```

> ```
> {tr[a^3], tr[a] tr[a^2], tr[a]^3}
> ```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jxx, you are most welcome. Thank you for the accept.